# Make snowballs damage using data merge

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to make snowballs damage players by modifying their data. I remember seeing a pack that could but cannot seem to find it.

How do I do what? what do I need to edit?

I tried HasBeenShot, LeftOwner, and the Owner UUID, nothing seems to be working.

I am not looking to simply apply the instant damage effect to entities near the snowball.

Comment: This video might help: https://youtu.be/yM7aQKAbFmY
It might work if you change the setblock to an effect give @p. However, I haven't tested it myself.